# How to add a virtual folder in Windows with C++

Tags: c++, c, mfc, cloud, windows-shell

I'm not sure if I'm using the correct terminology. Say, the SkyDrive app from Microsoft creates a virtual "Skydrive" folder on a local computer. What I'm curious to know is how to add such virtual folder with C++/MFC?

Comment: What do you mean by "add", can you give a scenario?

Comment: Well, when I install SkyDrive app it adds a folder named "Skydrive." That's what I mean by "add" ...

Comment: I broke out in hives when I saw C++/MFC. Seriously, I'm all itchy now.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: What would you code it with then?

Comment: Nothing personal. I just started having flashbacks to my Advanced C++ course and swearing extensively. `LPCTSTR`, `HWND`, `CWin`...ugh. Ill-advised Hungarian notation run wild. I wish you the best of luck. As far as what I would use to create a folder? Why not something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory(v=vs.71).aspx)? Unless there's something more complicated going on here.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: C# and the managed world is indeed easier to code with, but what really doesn't go well for me in that environment is the robustness (i.e. speed) of the resulting executables. That's a different subject though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a [virtual folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It is a system folder made by PathMakeSystemFolder, so the system knows you have some customization going on in desktop.ini. Skydrive merely customized the folder's icon.

Reference: [How to Customize Folders with Desktop.ini (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)